# How can I run Hadoop Streaming on Hadoop Cluster?

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, hadoop-streaming

Currently I have a Hadoop cluster with 3 nodes(ubuntu)

I want to run python / R scripts with Hadoop Streaming, but I am not sure whether just executing HS actually makes all nodes work or not

If it is possible, please give me direction to run Streaming on the cluster

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop streaming is a built-in jar/utility that allows you to create and run Map/Reduce jobs with any executable or script as the mapper and/or the reducer.

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -input myInputDirs \
    -output myOutputDir \
    -mapper /bin/cat \
    -reducer /bin/wc
```

In the above command, both the mapper and the reducer are executables that read the input from stdin (line by line) and emit the output to stdout. The utility will create a Map/Reduce job, submit the job to an appropriate cluster, and monitor the progress of the job until it completes.

-input: directory/file-name Input location for mapper.

-output: directory-name Output location for reducer.

-mapper: executable or script or JavaClassName  Required Mapper executable.

-reducer: executable or script or JavaClassName Required Reducer executable.

-file file-name: Makes the mapper, reducer, or combiner executable available locally on the compute nodes.

Ex 1: A user-defined python executable as the mapper. The option "-file myPythonScript.py" causes the python executable shipped to the cluster machines as a part of job submission.

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -input myInputDirs \
    -output myOutputDir \
    -mapper myPythonScript.py \
    -reducer /bin/wc \
    -file myPythonScript.py
```

Ex 2:Send an Java class as an argument to the mapper and/or the reducer

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -input myInputDirs \
    -output myOutputDir \
    -mapper org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper \
    -reducer /bin/wc
```

Source: [Hadoop Streaming jar](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html)